# How to get values and selected values from combobox inside jtable?

Tags: java, swing, combobox, jtable, jcombobox

Before making my question I will try and explaing what I need and am trying to do. I have set up a table where there are several columns displaying a combobox as the picture shows:

[picture http://www.freeimagehosting.net/newuploads/4ks9s.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/newuploads/4ks9s.png)

This is supposed to create an "order" for the jobs this meaning, Job 1 will first go to Station 1. If I add Station 4 on the Station 2 Column it would then go to Station 4, and so on. It is intended to create an order for further processing. So, I want to:

- Create the table and display the rendered combobox;
- Make the cells from columns (3-6) non-editable if the previous column has a value of "none" (thus making sure it keeps a correct order);
- Don't display a Station that has already been chosen for that row;

But for starters, I am not being able to get the values that are being set when choosing from the comboboxes nor am I able to get thosevales!

Heres is my code so far.

Creating the combobox:

```
public class SimGui extends JFrame {
                          //implements ActionListener {
    String Stations[] = new String[] {"Station 1","Station 2","Station 3","Station 4","Station 5","None"};
    JComboBox stationscombo = new JComboBox(Stations);
    Object obj = stationscombo.getSelectedItem();
```

Mouse Click event on the table:

```
private void jTable2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    //Object event = evt.getSource();
    obj = stationscombo.getSelectedItem();
    System.out.println("Item: " + obj);
    //ListSelectionModel selectionModel = jTable2.getSelectionModel();
    int tb1columns = jTable2.getColumnCount();
    int selectionrow= jTable2.getSelectedRow();
    int selectioncolumn = jTable2.getSelectedColumn();
    if (selectioncolumn > 1) {
        for (int i=2;i<tb1columns;i++) {
            System.out.println(jTable2.getValueAt(selectionrow,selectioncolumn));
            /*if (jTable2.getValueAt(selectionrow, i) != "None") {
                stationscombo.removeItem(jTable2.getValueAt(selectionrow, i));
            }*/
        }
    }
    else { System.out.println(jTable2.getValueAt(selectionrow,selectioncolumn)); }
}
```

The table construction:

```
jTable2.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
    new Object [][] {
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null}
    },
    new String [] {
        "Job Type", "Parts", "Station 1", "Station 2", "Station 3", "Station 4", "Station 5"
    }
) {
    Class[] types = new Class [] {
        java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class
    };
    boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
        false, true, true, true, true, true, true
    };

    public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return types [columnIndex];
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return canEdit [columnIndex];
    }
});
jTable2.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
for (int x = 2;x<7;x++) {
    jTable2.getColumnModel().getColumn(x).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(stationscombo));
}
jTable2.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        jTable2MouseClicked(evt);
    }
});
```

I have looked around and tried to implement a listener for the combobox but failed. If I implement ActionListener on the class it will display a warning saying that:

```
SimGui is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent) in java.awt.event.ActionListener
```

I have alreay an ActionListener implemented for the tables which is working, but I don't know if that might be interfering?

```
Action action = new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getSource());
        //TableCellListener tcl = (TableCellListener)e.getSource();
        //JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
        //String newSelection = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();
        /*JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
        String teste = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();
        System.out.println("Item: " + teste);*/
        //TableCellListener tcl1 = new TableCellListener(jTable1, action);
        /*if (tcl.getColumn() == 3) {
            if (tcl.getNewValue() == true) {
                int x = tcl.getColumn();
                table1model.setColumnEditable(x, true);
            }
            else { 
                table1model.setColumnEditable(tcl.getColumn(), false);
            }
            /*boolean canEdit[] = {
            false, true, true, true, true, true
            };
            //System.out.println(isCellEditable(tcl1.getRow(),tcl1.getColumn()));
        }*/
        /*System.out.println(newSelection);
        System.out.println("Row   : " + tcl.getRow());
        System.out.println("Column: " + tcl.getColumn());
        System.out.println("Old   : " + tcl.getOldValue());
        System.out.println("New   : " + tcl.getNewValue());*/
    }
};
```

But bottom line, my question is, how can I correctly work with the combobox inside the table so that I can get the values set and get the item value when selected?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [TableModel.setColumnValue(row, col)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#getValueAt%28int,%20int%29)

You might also like to do some reading up on [table cell editors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) as well, this will help you understand exactly what's going on.